# How do I group and filter the next list of objects?

Tags: python

Input is the list of tuples: `(string, list of integers)`

I need to select only tuples with unique list of integers (order matters) that have the shortest string value.

For example:

`[('s', [1,2]), ('ss', [1,2]), ('ss', [1,2,3]), ('ss', [1,3,2])] -> [('s', [1,2]), ('ss', [1,2,3]), ('ss', [1,3,2])]`

`('s', [1,2]), ('ss', [1,2])` have the same list `[1,2]` . Select tuple with shortest string value. In this case `('s', [1,2])`

What is the right way to group and filter (speed is important)?

In other words: group by list and take the shortest string.

Comment: to clarify you want to filter only the one with the right order of number??

Comment: filter tuples that have the same lists: [1,2]==[1,2] then filter. Order of items in list does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use the itertools `groupby` function.

Assuming your input list is:

```
unfiltered = [('s', [1,2]), ('ss', [1,2]), ('ss', [1,2,3]), ('ss', [1,3,2])]
```

This should give you what you're looking for:

```
from itertools import groupby

# group by value
key_func = lambda x: x[1]

# sort the input by the grouping criteria
# to conform with groupby's behavior - see comments
unfiltered_sorted = sorted(unfiltered, key=key_func)

# get one item per group. sorting the group by length
# instead of the default alphabetical order
filtered = [sorted(group, key=len)[0] for _, group in groupby(unfiltered_sorted, key_func)]
```

Comment: it does not sort by string value. It will not work for: `unfiltered = [('ss', [1,2]), ('s', [1,2]), ('ss', [1,2,3]), ('ss', [1,3,2])]`

Comment: @OlegDats you're right, added a sort call to get it sorted first.

Comment: interesting, `set().add([1,2])` does not work but `group by` works. Can you please explain?

Comment: from the docs it seems that `groupby` compares the value computed by the key function without hashing, while set fails on lists because it requires the object to be hashable and mutable objects aren't.

Comment: another thing to notice, this solution will not work on the following input: `[('a', [1]), ('b', [2]), ('bb', [2]), ('aa', [1])]` because groupby requires the input to first be sorted by the same key function that is used for grouping. you can solve this by first sorting the input with `key_func`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I spent last 15min thinking why it does not work on my real data (not sorted). Please, update you answer, it will be useful for somebody. Your solution is just 3 lines of code. Just wondering what solution is the most efficient from provided.

Comment: @OlegDats added. I also added the `key=len`, otherwise 'abc' will take precedence of 'ss'.

Answer (score 1):

Does order matter?

If not:

```py
input_ = [('s', [1, 2]), ('ss', [1, 2]), ('ss', [1, 2, 3]), ('ss', [1, 3, 2])]
expected = [('s', [1, 2]), ('ss', [1, 2, 3]), ('ss', [1, 3, 2])]


# sort by string length, then list length in reverse.
sorted_input = sorted(input_, key=lambda a: (len(a[0]), len(a[1])), reverse=True)

# then put that in dict, triggering it to overwrite the previous key.
temp_dict = {}

for (string, list_) in sorted_input:
    temp_dict[tuple(list_)] = string

# now convert back
output = [(string, list(list_)) for list_, string in reversed(temp_dict.items())]

print(f"output: {output} \nExpect: {expected}")
```

```
output: [('s', [1, 2]), ('ss', [1, 3, 2]), ('ss', [1, 2, 3])] 
Expect: [('s', [1, 2]), ('ss', [1, 2, 3]), ('ss', [1, 3, 2])]
```

Basically trick is:

1. Order by length-descending order.
2. Put it into dict. Convert list to tuple, then use it as key, and string as value.
3. As it's inserted into dict, if there's overlapping key(list), then it's overwritten by shorter strings as we sorted in descending order before.

You could save more time by removing tuple->list conversions at `output`.

---

To add, python's `dict.items()` cannot be reversed in <= python 3.7. in that case, reverse `list(dict.items())`.

Comment: TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not reversible

Comment: I never used dict_items, dict.items() that is.

Comment: @OlegDats if wondering, I'm using python 3.8~python3.10 and not getting any error.

Comment: reversed(dict().items()) produces TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not reversible

Comment: Show full code because that's not the code I wrote, or I have no way to help you. And reversing is not even needed if output's ordering is not important.

Comment: Just one line of code. I do not understand why it does not work. I use google colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10_sZ_D2tOsikAIWweLdfNgQIBK0hVVhe?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh I see, seems like it's older version of python! in that case, `reversed(list(dict().items))` should do?

Comment: yes, it works, thanks. It is clear that reversed is not needed and it is just to show result.

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
lst = [('s', [1,2]), ('ss', [1,2]), ('ss', [1,2,3]), ('ss', [1,3,2])]

def sort_lst(x):
    return len(x[0])

lst.sort(key=sort_lst)


result = [i for e,i in enumerate(lst) if i[1] not in [j[1] for j in lst[:e]]]
print(result)
```